# Sufficient Conditions for Determining the Orthogonal Complement

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, inner-products, orthogonality, direct-sum

Let $X$ be a Hilbert space with inner product denoted $(\cdot, \cdot)$, $V$ a closed subspace of $X$. Let
$$X=V \oplus U$$
and suppose $(u,v)=0$ for any $u \in U$ and any $v \in V$. Then, clearly $U \subset V^\perp$. Is it necessarily true that $U=V^\perp$?

Comment: Because $V$ is closed, $V^{\perp\perp} = V$. This will lead to $V=U^\perp$. If $U$ is not closed, the equality you want cannot hold.

Comment: @TedShifrin The linear subspace $U$ satisfying the given hypothesis is always closed.

Comment: Not quite the same question, but close to a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2646907/orthogonal-sum-with-non-closed-subspace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X=V\oplus V^{\perp}\tag{1}$

$X=V\oplus U\tag{2}$

Let $x\in V^{\perp}$, then $x\overset{\text{(1)}}=v+u$

for unique $v\in V, u\in U$

$\begin{align}&\langle x, v\rangle=0\\&\langle v+u, v\rangle=0\\&\|v\|^2=0\\&v=0\end{align}$

Hence $x=0+u=u\in U$

That's conclude $V^{\perp}\subset U$

Comment: *Correction: $x=v+u$ by $(2) $.